# Cómo llamar un archivo Python desde mi JavaScript / AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Tengo un archivo PHP el cual desde un botón me llama un archivo Python y lo ejecuta sin problemas. Pero yo estoy cambiando ese botón por un radio para poder realizar efectos de "activado" y "desactivado" y también le agrego un evento `onclick` "mostrar" pero el problema es que quiero llamar desde ese evento a mi archivo .py. Espero puedan ayudarme.

Archivo PHP (solo pongo el código HTML)

```
<form>
          <input type="radio" id="izquierdo1" name="valor1" value="Encender" 
onclick="Mostrar()" />
          <label for="izquierdo1" class="pos">IEncendido</label>
          <input type="radio" id="derecho1" name="valor1" value="Apagar" 
checked onclick="Ocultar()" />
          <label for="derecho1">IApagado</label>
        </form>
```

Archivo Python

```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
   import time 
   #Configuramos los pines
   GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
   GPIO.setwarnings(False)
   led = 21
   #Pin 1 como salida
   GPIO.setup(led, GPIO.OUT)
   #Pin ON
   GPIO.output(led, True)
```

Deseo poder llamarlo desde mi evento `onclick`, espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Hi.. the official language of the site is spanish. If spanish is your first language, please translate it.

Comment: sorry pensé que estaba en el foro de ingles, ahora mismo lo traduzco, rgacias.